# How to get the C# WebDriver Windows to use SwitchTo with IE and new windows

Tags: c#, webdriver

I'm still new to C# programming and have been able to get WebDriver working properly to do much of the work I need to do on our site, except when new windows are launched.  Seems there are a lot of options to handle this within Java, but I can't seem to make the leap to C# in how to collect the Window Handles and then switch to the newly spawned one.  Part of the problem I am facing is that since it takes a few seconds for the new window to populate I am trying a wait to be able to capture the new window.  When I originally did this I tried using

```
wait.Until(WebDriver => driver.Title.Equals("_blank"));
driver.SwitchTo().Window("_blank")
```

to make sure the Window is spawned before trying to switch to it.

Then reading more on this I found I had to capture the windowHandles before making the switch, and since I still need to wait for the Window to spawn and populate I guess I need some kind of while to check for the new handle and switch to it, and at that point I am not sure what to do.

I'm using selenium2's .Net WebDriver, with SpecFlow so all the tests are in C# and I feel more comfortable in doing C# than Java, though I have not done much advanced work with C#.  If anyone has some tips to get me started on how to resolve this I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET support classes in WebDriver.Support.dll have a PopupWindowFinder class designed to help exactly this scenario. It's listed as experimental at the moment, but at the very least, you could examine the code of [that class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dotnet/src/WebDriver.Support/UI/PopupWindowFinder.cs) to see how it works. It might give you some insights on how to code your own, if it doesn't exactly meet your needs.